# Getting a variable back from a $.ajax request

Tags: jquery

I want to run an ajax request within a function. Basically...

```
function doIt(id) {
    var myVar;
    $.ajax({
        ... url etc...
        success: function(result) {
            myVar = "Some stuff" + result;
            console.log(myVar);
        }
    })
    return myVar;
}
```

but myvar isn't set to what it is when I log it after on success.  How can I get that variable retuned by the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't finish before the next line is executed. What is happening is that `return myVar;` is being executed before the `success` event triggers.

Turn the `async` property off and that will superficially fix your problem:

```
function doIt(id) {
    var myVar;
    $.ajax({
        ... url etc...,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            myVar = "Some stuff" + result;
            console.log(myVar);
        }
    })
    return myVar;
}
```

However, that will make your browser hang, so the best way to approach this is to put all processing inside of the `success` event.

```
function doIt(id) {
    var myVar;
    $.ajax({
        ... url etc...,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            myVar = "Some stuff" + result;
            console.log(myVar);
            // TODO: Everything related to `myVar` here.
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: @justing , async false is not goodway as it blocks the user until it finishes instead do your operation in the success

Comment: This is generally a terrible idea as the browser will hang until the request completes.  There are some reasons to do this, but not many good ones.

Comment: `async: false` will lock up the browser until the call is done.  I suggest not doing this.  Instead I suggest changing how you're using the `myVar` value.

Answer (score 3):

The ajax call is aysnc , so it happens parallely that is reason you are not getting the result

You cannot return the value like that
`var myVar;`

```
function doIt(id) {

    $.ajax({
        ... url etc...
        success: function(result) {
            myVar = "Some stuff" + result;
            console.log(myVar);
            // do your logic here after the ajax success
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a value from an AJAX call.  It's asynchronous.  The `return` runs before the AJAX call finishes.

You need to do all logic pertaining to `myVar` inside the callback.